# How to remove newline after ls within perl?

Tags: perl, newline

I am using perl under `cygwin`. Here is what I want to do. I want to list all the folders under a directory into an array and then print them out as a string such that I have the following result.

Let, the working path is `/user/`.
Folders inside the path are:

```
/user/A
/user/B
/user/C
```

I want to:

```
perl foo
/user/A /user/B /user/C
```

I have the following code:

```
my @folderList = `ls /user`;
foreach (@folderList) {
    print "$_ ";
}
print "\n";
```

**But**, the result is:

```
$ perl foo
/user/A
/user/B
/user/C
$
```

**My question**:
How to remove the newline of every result stored inside the array? I have tried chop() to remove the last char but it is not working.

Comment: sorry, I fixed the code. Since my original function is a little bit complex, so I just figure out a part of it so that it is easier for me to solve my problem step by step ~"~

Comment: OK, so ... if I put `chop;` inside the loop, immediately before `print "$_ ";`, your code works for me.  I already gave an answer showing what you _should have_ written, but I'd like to understand why `chop` didn't work for you.  Exactly how did you try to use it?

Comment: @zwol `chop` will remove the last character in a string regardless of what it is.  Aside from the obvious problems with that, Windows uses two characters for a newline so it's non-portable.  I'm not sure what Cygwin commands use, probably the single character Unix newline.

Comment: @Schwern I'm aware of this - I would normally never use `chop`, but it is what the OP said they tried.  The possibility of `\r\n` being truncated to `\r` which then itself acts as a line terminator had not occurred to me, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) which will strip the newlines off a `$string` or `@strings`.

But your implementation has some problems.  The biggest is using system commands like `cat` and `ls` to do things Perl can already do.  You should avoid using system commands when possible because its generally slower (actually the commands are often faster than Perl but the overhead of doing the work to run them is slower), non-portable (if you didn't have Cygwin your code won't work on Windows), insecure (it's very easy for a user to inject shell code into what you think is just a filename), harder to error check (you need to scrape the STDERR output rather than read `$!`), and you never know if you're getting the BSD or GNU version (a particular problem with things like find).

Instead use functions like [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html), [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html), and [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to read files and directories.

Better yet, use the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module which takes care of most file operations for you.  And it takes care of checking for errors as well, no `or die $!` sprinkled everywhere.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

my $dir = path("/user");

for my $subdir ($dir->children) {
    say $subdir->absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`chomp` is the way to go -- you can do something like this:

```
my @folderList = `find user -mindepth 1`;

foreach (@folderList) {
    chomp $_;
    print "$_ ";
}
print "\n";
```

**Note:** you might want to change "`find user -mindepth 1`" to the unix command which fits your needs

Comment: I believe you meant `-maxdepth`.

Comment: If you're going to use `$_` (and you shouldn't, you should use `foreach my $dir`), you might as well take advantage and write `chomp;` and `print;`.  Or just `chomp @folderList` and get it out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goals correctly,

```
perl -MCwd -le 'print join " ", glob getcwd. "/*"'
```

or more canonically

```
use Cwd;
print(join(" ", glob(getcwd() . "/*"), "\n"));
```

is the program you *should have* written.  This bypasses the whole problem by using the built-in Perl function [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) and the standard library function [`Cwd::getcwd`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) to do the directory scan, rather than invoking a subprocess.  (As a rule of thumb, if you *can* do something without invoking a subprocess, you *should* do it without invoking a subprocess.  You will know when you encounter the exceptions to this rule.)

You could loop over the output of `glob`, but using `join` instead means there is no trailing space.